# How to reference a 2d pointer?

Tags: c++

In my code I create a function outside of the main, which creates a 1D array and initializes to 0.

```
void create_grid(double *&y, int Npoints)
{
    y = new double[Npoints];
    for (int i = 0; i < Npoints; i++)
    {
        y[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

If I didn't have the syntax of declaring in the function as `double *&y` I couldn't access the values of `y`.

I tried doing the same for a 2D array but i don't know the syntax. I tried `&&**y` and `&*&*y` but it didn't work. Does anyone know how to create a function outside of the main, which initializes a 2d dynamic array so I can use it in the main?

E.g.:

```
void create_grid_2D(double **&&y, int Npoints1, int Npoints2)
{
    y = new double*[Npoints1];
    for (int i = 0; i < Npoints1; i++)
    {
        y[i] = new double[Npoints2];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Npoints1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Npoints2; j++)
        {
            y[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int N = 10;
    double **z;//correcting this line, i wrote z** 
    create_grid_2D(z, N, N);
    delete[]z;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: a pointer is `*y`, double pointer, `**y`. Adding the referencing operator `&` is confusing... Actually it looks like you are cancelling out the pointer

Comment: Try this:  `std::vector<std::vector<double>>& y`

Comment: don't use raw pointers and manual explicit memory management (`new`/`delete`). Use standard containers, e.g. `std::vector`

Comment: I suppose you want to use raw arrays and pointers (for the sake of the exercise). If you want to create 2D-arrays of arbitrary dimensions you must create an array of pointers to other arrays (not a real 2-D array, even if you access it with a[i][j]). You can make that a template where the dimensions (e.g. your Npoints) are compile-time template parameters instead of run-time function arguments.

Answer (score 1):

An easy trick to resolve/write such complicated references is (simplified version for the sake of this problem - it's a bit more complicated with braces present): start from the variable name and go to the left, step by step. In your case:

> ... `y`

`y` is ...

> ... `& y`

`y` is a reference ...

> ... `*& y`

`y` is a reference to a pointer ...

> ... `**& y`

`y` is a reference to a pointer to a pointer ...

> `double**& y`

`y` is a reference to a pointer to a pointer to a double

So, the correct definition is:

```
void create_grid_2D(double**& y,int Npoints1,int Npoints2)
```

But as mentioned in the comments, please do really consider avoiding raw pointers in favor of `std::vector` and other standard containers.

Comment: Thank you, very clear explanation and answer to "asked question". If I would need to write C equivalent and change function sign to (double*** y...), would I need to deference y everytime (*y) I use it or can I assign deferenced y to some variable?

Comment: @unlut Depending on what you need, you use the exact number of `*`s before the variable, to "cancel" the same number of `*`s from the variable's type.

Comment: @NunoTeixeira They are error prone, not very readable and not very convenient (as you're experiencing yourself just now). Containers are easier to use, safer and in most use cases as efficient as raw pointers.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not allow forming a pointer to reference or reference to reference.  (And without a space between the characters, `&&` is a single token meaning something entirely different.)

And your declaration `double z**;` is incorrect - you probably mean `double **z;`.

To write a function that takes the argument `double **z` by reference, you just want a reference to pointer to pointer:

```
void create_grid_2D(double **&y,int Npoints1,int Npoints2)
{
    //...
}
```

Except don't use `new` and `delete`.  Using them slightly wrong leads to memory leaks and bugs with dangling pointers and double deletes.  For example, you tried to clean up your memory in `main` with `delete []z;`, but new-expressions were evaluated 11 times to your one delete-expression, so this misses out on deleting the row arrays `z[0]`, `z[1]`, ... `z[9]`.  There's pretty much always a better and simpler way using `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, `std::vector`, or other RAII (Resource Allocation Is Initialization) tools.

So I would change the function to:

```
void create_grid_2D(std::vector<std::vector<double>>& y,
                    unsigned int Npoints1,
                    unsigned int Npoints2)
{
    y.assign(Npoints1, std::vector<double>(Npoints2, 0.0));
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int N=10;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> z;
    create_grid_2D(z, N, N);
    // No manual cleanup necessary.
}
```

Or even use a return value rather than assigning an argument:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> create_grid_2D(
    unsigned int Npoints1,
    unsigned int Npoints2)
{
    return std::vector<std::vector<double>>(
        Npoints1, std::vector<double>(Npoints2, 0.0));
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int N=10;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> z = create_grid_2D(N, N);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want a reference on a pointer to a pointer.

2d pointer is `int**`, and the reference is `int**&`. That's what you want to use.

Then, you should a container or at least a smart pointer instead.

Answer (score 0):

This approach would be a little different than what you currently have but basically you want a 2D grid and another name for this is simply a MxN Matrix! We can do this very easily with a simple template structure. This template class will hold all of the contents without having to put the data into dynamic memory directly. Then once you have your class object that you want to use we can then put that into dynamic memory with the use of smart pointers!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<class T, unsigned M, unsigned N>
class Matrix {
    static const unsigned Row = M;
    static const unsigned Col = N;
    static const unsigned Size = Row * Col;
    T data[Size] = {};

public: 
    Matrix() {};
    Matrix( const T* dataIn ) {
        fillMatrix( dataIn );
    }

    void fillMatrix( const T* dataIn );
    void printMatrix() const;
};

template<class T, unsigned M, unsigned N>
void Matrix<T, M, N>::fillMatrix( const T* dataIn ) {
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < Size; i++ ) {
        this->data[i] = dataIn[i];
    }
}

template<class T, unsigned M, unsigned N>
void Matrix<T,M,N>::printMatrix() {
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < Row; i++ ) {
        for ( unsigned j = 0; j < Col; j++ ) {
            std::cout << this->data[i*Col + j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {

    // our 1 day array of data
    double data[6] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 };

    // create and print a MxN matrix - in memory still a 1 day array but represented as 2D array
    Matrix<double,2,3> A;
    A.fillMatrix( data );
    A.printMatrix();
    std::cout << '\n';

    Matrix<double, 3,2> B( data );
    B.printMatrix();
    std::cout << '\n';

    // Want this in dynamic memory? With shared_ptr the memory is handled for you
    // and is cleaned up upon it's destruction. This helps to eliminate memory leaks
    // and dangling pointers.
    std::shared_ptr<Matrix<float,2,3>> pMatrix( new Matrix<float,2,3>( data ) );

    pMatrix->printMatrix();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6

1 2 
3 4
5 6

1 2 3
4 5 6
```